# How to prove using Ferrer's diagrams?

Tags: combinatorics

Using Ferrer's diagrams, show that the number of partitions of $n$ into parts of size 1 or 2 is equal to the number of partitions of $n$ into two parts.

Answer (score 2):

It isn’t: it’s equal to the number of partitions of $n$ into **at most** two parts. The concept that you want is the [*conjugate*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29#Ferrers_diagram) of a partition.

**Added:** Here’s the Ferrers diagram of a partition whose parts all have sizes $1$ or $2$:

$$\begin{align*}
&\bullet\bullet\\
&\bullet\bullet\\
&\bullet\\
&\bullet\\
&\bullet
\end{align*}$$

And here is the Ferrers diagram of its conjugate partition:

$$\begin{align*}
&\bullet\bullet\bullet\bullet\bullet\\
&\bullet\bullet
\end{align*}$$

Notice that it has two parts. Here’s another example:

$$\begin{align*}
&\bullet\bullet\\
&\bullet\bullet\\
&\bullet\bullet\\
&\bullet\bullet\\
&\bullet\bullet
\end{align*}$$

And its conjugate:

$$\begin{align*}
&\bullet\bullet\bullet\bullet\bullet\\
&\bullet\bullet\bullet\bullet\bullet\end{align*}$$

And one more example:

$$\begin{align*}
&\bullet\\
&\bullet\\
&\bullet\\
&\bullet\\
&\bullet
\end{align*}$$

And its conjugate

$$\bullet\bullet\bullet\bullet\bullet$$

Comment: And how can I do this?

Comment: @aaaaa: Did you read the material at the link? What does the conjugate of a partition of $n$ into parts of size $1$ and $2$ look like?

Comment: I did, but I don't know how to prove it. I don't have any idea.

Comment: @aaaaa: Do you see that the conjugate of a partition whose parts have sizes $1$ or $2$ is always a partition with $1$ or $2$ parts, and *vice versa*? Use that relation to define a bijection between the set of partitions with parts of size $1$ or $2$ and the set of partitions into at most two parts.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Change your direction of viewing the diagram.